# Nativescript horizontal scroll works perfectly but not with item template

Tags: javascript, nativescript, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to create a horizontal scrolling set of items using an item template from a dynamic list. The following manual code works as expected - a horizontally scrolling list of 'tickets':

```
<ScrollView orientation="horizontal">
  <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="scroll-menu">
        <StackLayout class="ticket-panel">
          <Label text="A ticket" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout class="ticket-panel">
          <Label text="A ticket" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout class="ticket-panel">
          <Label text="A ticket" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout class="ticket-panel">
           <Label text="A ticket" />
        </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But the following does not. It scrolls vertically. Does the itemTemplate insert more xml into the list than when I use itemTemplate?

```
<ScrollView orientation="horizontal">
  <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="scroll-menu">
    <ListView items="{{ ticketList }}">
      <ListView.itemTemplate>
        <StackLayout class="ticket-panel">
         <Label text="A ticket" />
        </StackLayout>
      </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You are not suppose to use ScrollView with ListView. Try using [RadListView](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/radlistview/item-layouts) with ListViewLinearLayout and set scrollDirection to horizontal.

Comment: I'll try that Manoj thanks

Comment: RadListView works perfectly! Can't mark your answer as correct though, coz it's a comment